# Supress Redirecting by triggering a form action using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I would like to use flask to define the action for a button. However, after triggering the action, I will automatically be redirected. E.g. having a button definition using the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/do_something" method="post">
    <button>Do something!</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the action handling by the given python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def root():
    return render_template("test_3.html")


@app.route("/do_something", methods=["POST"])
def something():
    return 'Something'


app.run()
```

In this case, I start with the url "/". By clicking on the button "Do Something", I will automatically be redirected to the url "/do_something". What I actual want is:

1. Perform Action
2. Refresh the original page

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

If the POST request to `/do_something` can occur on any page, I would recommend redirecting back to the request's referrer, which will "refresh" the page.

E.g

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def root():
    return render_template("test_3.html")


@app.route("/do_something", methods=["POST"])
def something():
    # Do things
    return redirect(request.referrer or request.host_url)

app.run()
```

Otherwise you can specify the page to go to with `redirect()` and `url_for()`

Example:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def root():
    return render_template("test_3.html")


@app.route("/do_something", methods=["POST"])
def something():
    # Do things
    return redirect(url_for("app.root"))


app.run()
```